# ion-select popover interface is not getting hidden on hardware back button action

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, hybrid-mobile-app

I used the popover interface on `<ion-select>` to display pop-over. In an Android device, if the user taps on ion-select but didn't select any option and click the hardware back button, it moves to the previous view but popover interface is still visible. Please help.

```html
<ion-select interface="popover" [(ngModel)]="item.productType" placeholder="Please select" multiple="false" ionChange="onChange($event)" >
    <ion-option *ngFor="let opt of options" [value]="opt.value">{{opt.label}}</ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

Comment: `if user tap on ion-select but didn't select any option` are you sure that there is popping after you click ion-select?

Comment: there is a popping after user select any option from pop over but user just tap on ion-select>>pop-over appears>> click android back button>> pop-over is not popping out.Please help

Answer (score 0):

Define page name in **modal page**.

```
pageName = "ModalPage";
```

Then register backbutton in **app.component.ts**

```
    this.platform.registerBackButtonAction(() => {
        let nav = this.app.getActiveNav();
        let view = nav.getActive().instance.pageName;

        if (view == 'ModalPage') {
            let activeView: ViewController =  nav.getActive();
            activeView.dismiss();
       } else {
          this.nav.pop();
      }
    }
```

Basically it will register your device backbutton to perform action when particular modal opened.

**Feel free to comment for more help :)**

Comment: This may work if i create any modalpage but here im using ion-select  pop-over. this is not working for ion-select I tried using  @ViewChild('myselect') select: Select; and in  ionWillLeave I am closing this.select.close(); this is working fine. But I have select field based on some condition , those select fields are not working if use @viewchild and getting error as undefined. Please help